# Read non-blocking from multiple fifos in parallel

Tags: merge, cat, fifo, parallel-processing

I sometimes sit with a bunch of output fifos from programs that run in parallel. I would like to merge these fifos. The naïve solution is:

```
cat fifo* > output
```

But this requires the first fifo to complete before reading the first byte from the second fifo, and this will block the parallel running programs.

Another way is:

```
(cat fifo1 & cat fifo2 & ... ) > output
```

But this may mix the output thus getting half-lines in output.

When reading from multiple fifos, there must be some rules for merging the files. Typically doing it on a line by line basis is enough for me, so I am looking for something that does:

```
parallel_non_blocking_cat fifo* > output
```

which will read from all fifos in parallel and merge the output on with a full line at a time.

I can see it is not hard to write that program. All you need to do is:

1. open all fifos
2. do a blocking select on all of them
3. read nonblocking from the fifo which has data into the buffer for that fifo
4. if the buffer contains a full line (or record) then print out the line
5. if all fifos are closed/eof: exit
6. goto 2

So my question is **not**: can it be done?

My question is: Is it done already and can I just install a tool that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution will only work if the number of fifos are fewer than the number of jobs that GNU parallel can run in parallel (which is limited by file handles and number of processes):

```
parallel -j0 --line-buffer cat ::: fifo*
```

It seems to be able to move up to 500 MB/s:

```
window1$ mkfifo {1..100}
window1$ parallel -j0 --line-buffer cat ::: {1..100} | pv >/dev/null

window2$ parallel -j0 'cat bigfile > ' ::: *
```

And it does not mix half-lines:

```
window1$ mkfifo {1..100}
window1$ parallel -j0 --line-buffer cat ::: {1..100} &

window2$ parallel -j0 'traceroute {}.1.1.1 > {}' ::: *
```

It reads jobs in parallel (it does not read one job completely before going to the next):

```
window1$ mkfifo {1..100}
window1$ parallel -j0 --line-buffer cat ::: * > >(tr -s ABCabc)

window2$ long_lines_with_pause() {
            perl -e 'print STDOUT "a"x30000_000," "'                                                      
    perl -e 'print STDOUT "b"x30000_000," "'                                                      
    perl -e 'print STDOUT "c"x30000_000," "'                                                      
    echo "$1"                                                                                     
    sleep 2                                                                                       
    perl -e 'print STDOUT "A"x30000_000," "'                                                      
    perl -e 'print STDOUT "B"x30000_000," "'                                                      
    perl -e 'print STDOUT "C"x30000_000," "'                                                      
    echo "$1"                                                                                     
}
window2$ export -f long_lines_with_pause
window2$ parallel -j0 'long_lines_with_pause {} > {}' ::: *
```

Here a lot of 'a b c' (first half of a job) will be printed before 'A B C' (second half of the job).

Answer (score 1):

So,

```
tail -q -n+1 -f --pid=stop-tail-when-this-is-gone fifo1 fifo2 fifo3
```

*almost* works (as alluded to in initial comments about this earlier version of my answer, though you may need a "for f in fifo*; cat < /dev/null > $f & done" beforehand to ensure all FIFOs are open for write because coreutils tail opens them O_RDONLY without O_NONBLOCK).

Unfortunately, there is a bug in that `tail` is careful about line/record endings only with inputs from pipes on stdin but not with input from named pipes/FIFOs in arguments.  Someday someone may fix coreutils tail.

In the interim, to get a true multi-consumer/single producer queue honoring the line-endings, you can use a simple 100-ish-line C program I call `tailpipes.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>    //TODO: Find&document build environments lacking memrchr
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#define errstr strerror(errno)

char const * const Use = "%s: %s\n\nUsage:\n\n"
"  %s [-p PID] [-o OPEN_MODE(RW)] [-d DLM(\\n)] [-s SEC(.01)] PATH1 PATH2..\n\n"
"Read delimited records (lines by default) from all input paths, writing only\n"
"complete records to stdout and changing to a stop-at-EOF mode upon receiving\n"
"SIGHUP (unlike \"tail -fqn+1\" which just dies) OR when we first notice that\n"
"PID does not exist (if PID is given).  Since by default fifos are opened RW,\n"
"signal/PID termination is needed to not loop forever, but said FIFOs may be\n"
"closed & reopened by other processes as often as is convenient. For one-shot\n"
"writing style, ending input reads at the first EOF, use \"-oRO\".  Also, DLM\n"
"adjusts the record delimiter byte from the default newline, and SEC adjusts\n"
"max select sleep time.  Any improperly terminated final records are sent to\n"
"stderr at the end of execution (with a label and bracketing).\n";

int writer_done;
void sig(int signum) { writer_done = 1; }

int main(int N, char *V[]) {
    signed char     ch;
    char           *buf[N-1], delim = '\n', *V0 = V[0], *eol;
    int             len[N-1], fds[N-1], nBf[N-1], i, fdMx = 0, nS = 0, nF = 0,
                    oFlags = O_RDWR;
    pid_t           pid = 0;
    ssize_t         nR, nW;
    struct timespec tmOut = { 0, 10000000 }; //10 ms select time out
    fd_set          fdRdMaster, fdRd;
    //If we get signaled before here, this program dies and data may be lost.
    //If possible use -p PID option w/pre-extant PID of appropriate lifetime.
    signal(SIGHUP, sig);                    //Install sig() for SIGHUP
    memset((void *)fds, 0, sizeof fds);
    memset((void *)len, 0, sizeof len);
    FD_ZERO(&fdRdMaster);
    fdRd = fdRdMaster;
    while ((ch = getopt(N, V, "d:p:s:o:")) != -1)
        switch (ch) {                       //For \0 do '' as a sep CLI arg
            double tO;
            case 'd': delim  = optarg ? *optarg : '\n';   break;
            case 'p': pid    = optarg ? atoi(optarg) : 0; break;
            case 's': tO = optarg ? atof(optarg) : .01;
                      tmOut.tv_sec = (long)tO;
                      tmOut.tv_nsec = 1e9 * (tO - tmOut.tv_sec);
                      break;
            case 'o': oFlags = (optarg && strcasecmp(optarg, "ro") == 0) ?
                                 O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK : O_RDWR;
                      break;
            default: return fprintf(stderr, Use, V0, "bad option", V0), 1;
        }
    V += optind; N -= optind;               //Shift off option args
    if (N < 1)
        return fprintf(stderr, Use, V0, "too few arguments", V0), 2;
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 65536);   //Full pipe on Linux
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)                 //Check for any available V[]
        if ((fds[i] = open(V[i], oFlags)) != -1) {
            struct stat st;
            fstat(fds[i], &st);
            if (!S_ISFIFO(st.st_mode))
                return fprintf(stderr,"%s: %s not a named pipe\n", V0, V[i]), 3;
            nF++;
            FD_SET(fds[i], &fdRdMaster);    //Add fd to master copy for pselect
            buf[i] = malloc(nBf[i] = 4096);
            if (fds[i] > fdMx)
                fdMx = fds[i];
        } else if (errno == EINTR) {        //We may get signaled to finish up..
            i--; continue;                  //..before we even this far.
        } else
            return fprintf(stderr, "%s: open(%s): %s\n", V0, V[i], errstr), 3;
    fdMx++;
    fdRd = fdRdMaster;
    while (nF && (nS = pselect(fdMx, &fdRd, NULL, NULL, &tmOut, NULL)) != -99) {
        if (pid && kill(pid, 0) != 0 && errno != EPERM) //Given pid didn't exist
            writer_done = 1;
        if (nS == 0 && writer_done)                     //No input & no writers
            break;
        else if (nS == -1) {                            //Some select error:
            if (errno != EINTR && errno == EAGAIN)      //..fatal or retry
                return fprintf(stderr, "%s: select: %s\n", V0, errstr), 4;
            continue;
        }
        for (i = 0; nS > 0 && i < N; i++) {             //For all fds..
            if (fds[i] < 0 || !FD_ISSET(fds[i], &fdRd)) //with readable data
                continue;
            if ((nR = read(fds[i], buf[i]+len[i], nBf[i] - len[i])) < 0) {
                if (errno != EAGAIN && errno != EINTR)
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s: read: %s\n", V0, errstr);
                continue;
            } else if (oFlags == (O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK) && nR == 0) {
                FD_CLR(fds[i], &fdRdMaster);
                nF--;
                free(buf[i]);
            }
            len[i] += nR;                               //Update Re: read data
            if ((eol = memrchr(buf[i], delim, len[i]))) {
                nW = eol - buf[i] + 1;                  //Only to last delim
                if (fwrite(buf[i], nW, 1, stdout) == 1) {
                    memmove(buf[i], buf[i] + nW, len[i] - nW);
                    len[i] -= nW;                       //Residual buffer shift
                } else
                    return fprintf(stderr, "%s: %d bytes->stdout failed: %s\n",
                                   V0, len[i], errstr), 5;
            } else if (len[i] == nBf[i]) {              //NoDelim&FullBuf=>GROW
                void *tmp;
                if (nBf[i] >= 1 << 30)
                    return fprintf(stderr, "%s: record > 1 GiB\n", V0), 6;
                nBf[i] *= 2;
                if (!(tmp = realloc(buf[i], nBf[i])))
                    return fprintf(stderr,"%s: out of memory\n", V0), 7;
                buf[i] = tmp;
            }
        }
        fdRd = fdRdMaster;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)                     //Ensure any residual data is..
        if (len[i] > 0) {                       //..labeled,bracketed,=>stderr.
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s: final unterminated record: {", V0, V[i]);
            fwrite(buf[i], len[i], 1, stderr);
            fputs("}\n", stderr);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Install is cut & paste & `cc -Owhatever tailpipes.c -o somewhere-in-$PATH/tailpipes`.  Tested on Linux & FreeBSD.  I get about 2500e6 bytes/sec output, but memory may be faster than the 500e6 bytes/sec box.

The algorithm is roughly as suggested, but more general.  O_NONBLOCK is only needed with O_RDONLY and with some options for ease of use, like opening FIFOs O_RDWR by default so writers can close and reopen many times and use -p PID tracking for a race-free protocol. You can pass -oRO to use EOF if you want.  `tailpipes` also handles incomplete lines at program termination, sending them labeled and bracketed to stderr in case there is easy post-processing that can be done to make the records whole or if logs of them would be useful for debugging.

Example usage. GNU `xargs` can be a single-consumer, multi-producer/fan-out part of a map-reduce-ish parallel pipeline with `tailpipes` operating as the record-boundary-honoring fan-in part, all with no disk space used for temporary files:

```
export MYTEMP=$(mktemp -d /tmp/MYPROG.XXXXX)
FIFOs=`n=0; while [ $n -lt 8 ]; do echo $MYTEMP/$n; n=$((n+1)); done`
mkfifo $FIFOs
sleep 2147483647 & p=$!       #Cannot know xargs pid is good for long
( find . -print0 | xargs -0 -P8 --process-slot-var=MYSLOT MYPROGRAM
  kill $p ) &                 #Inform tailpipes writers are done
tailpipes -p$p $FIFOs | CONSUMING-PIPELINE
rm -rf $MYTEMP
wait                          #Wait for xargs subshell to finish
```

In the above, it is important that A) `n` goes from `0` to the appropriate upper bound because that is the scheme `xargs` uses for `MYSLOT`, and B) `MYPROGRAM` direct its outputs to a newly assigned `$MYSLOT`-keyed file like `$MYTEMP/$MYSLOT`, e.g. `exec > $MYTEMP/$MYSLOT` if `MYPROGRAM` is a shell script.  The shell/program wrapper could be eliminated in many cases if `xargs` took a hypothetical `--process-slot-out` to setup its kids stdouts.

Comment: I tested this. It does not work on my CygWin system: If I only send data to `fifo3` nothing happens. What should happen is that the data on `fifo3` should be printed. You seem to be assuming that the producers will be producing all the time. That is not a safe assumption.

Comment: Your tail is probably blocking on the open for write of fifo1 and fifo2.  It's fine for some producers to never produce anything, but some process does need to open each for write, as per my explanation of the 'cat' loop in the more detailed example.

Comment: Now I get non-blocking, but mixing lines - which is the same as my `cat fifo1 &` example. Can you adapt your example to show that you can deal with programs like `traceroute` which spits out half-lines?

Comment: Personally, I prefer reproducible examples of errors, but I was able to get mixed up output like this:

    #!/bin/sh
    sleep 1000 &
    tail --pid=$! -qfn+1 0 1 > out &
    ( (echo -n a; sleep 1; echo b; sleep 1; echo -n c) > 0 &
      (echo 1; echo -n 2) > 1 &
      wait
      pkill -P$$ sleep ) # or killall sleep, etc.
     wait
cat out

Huh.  I cannot get the formatting to work in the comment box, I did get a "c1" line with that and numbers and letters should not be mixed up.  In light of bugs like this, I updated my answer to provide a C program more reliable for this usage.

Comment: "Huh. I cannot get the formatting to work in the comment box," And you now answered why I did not include an MCVE in the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant answer that does not buffer a useless copy on disk:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                                       

use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Thread::Queue;

my $done :shared;

my $DataQueue = Thread::Queue->new();

my @producers;
for (@ARGV) {
    push @producers, threads->create('producer', $_);
}

while($done <= $#ARGV) {
    # This blocks until $DataQueue->pending > 0                                                                       
    print $DataQueue->dequeue();
}

for (@producers) {
    $_->join();
}


sub producer {
    open(my $fh, "<", shift) || die;
    while(<$fh>) {
        $DataQueue->enqueue($_);
    }
    # Closing $fh blocks                                                                                              
    # close $fh;                                                                                                      
    $done++;
    # Guard against race condition                                                                                    
    $DataQueue->enqueue("");
}
```